# How to get only the latest doc with aggregation in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using the MongoDB aggregation to fetch all reports with the following steps:

```
[ { '$match': { name: 'test' } },
  { '$sort': { timestamp: -1 } } ]
```

I want to add a step that will get the last added report by timestamp. So I will get only one latest report. Which step should I add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're sorting on `timestamp` in descending order so the first document after sort stage will be the latest, So you need to use [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/index.html) to get one document out.

```
[ { '$match': { name: 'test' } },
  { '$sort': { timestamp: -1 } },
  {'$limit': 1} ]
```